# remove or undo rating google playstore review

Tags: app-ratings

due to privacy reasons - How do I remove a rating I put from the Android app in the Google play store?  I just realized people can see more of info and do not want that.  I can't find where to undo my rating.  I just clicked on the stars, did not write a review.

Answer (score 5):

You can delete your review/rating from both the Play store app page and also via the Play store on your device.

**Web Play Store**

Simply visit the page for the app for which you want to remove your review. Scroll down and you should see your review and also two buttons, 'delete' and 'edit'. Clicking the delete will remove your review.

[image: Web play store]

**Play Store app**
Visit the app for which you want to remove your review. Just beneath the app screenshots you should see your star 'review'. On the right there is an 'edit' button. Click this and you will then see a 'delete' button. Click this to delete your review.

[image: Play store app screenshot]